# Anything like layout manager in Java for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

Guys, I am a newbee for iOS. 
I need to create dynamic layout since the GUI will be generated according to the data.
I checked the UIView references, it seems the standard way to add subview is like:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
[someView addSubView: label];
```

But, maybe I can't be sure that the width and the height. In Java, container use layout manager to automatically deal with the width and height based on some rules. In iOS, can I use something like layout manager in Java?

Thanks.
Any clue will be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in iOS, although it is not one-to-one with Java layouts.  The get the idea of what is possible, use the Size Inspector in Interface Builder.  Anything that is done there, such as allowing an item to grow horizontally or stay the same distance from the top, can be done programmatically.  If further customization is needed, you can override event hooks in your view or controller, such as UIView's `-layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will check out what I can do in -layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9 provides [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) class which in essence is a layout manager:

> The UIStackView class provides a streamlined interface for laying out
>   a collection of views in either a column or a row. Stack views let you
>   leverage the power of Auto Layout, creating user interfaces that can
>   dynamically adapt to the device’s orientation, screen size, and any
>   changes in the available space. The stack view manages the layout of
>   all the views in its arrangedSubviews property. These views are
>   arranged along the stack view’s axis, based on their order in the
>   arrangedSubviews array. The exact layout varies depending on the stack
>   view’s axis, distribution, alignment, spacing, and other properties.

[image: UIStackView]

Note that it's not applicable if you're supporting iOS 8 which is still pretty actual at the moment.

[image: iOS version statistics]